# Kernel error while attempting to install VirtualBox using Exagear Desktop

Tags: pi-3, jessie-lite, virtualization

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba59j.jpg

See the photo for exact error - it has to do with the kernel. I'm using a RPi3 running Jessie Lite with exagear desktop installed.

Bottom line is that I need to play a Linux x86 .vmdk on the ARM Pi.

Is there a way to trick virtual box/install appropriate headers in order to run virtual box?

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

Comment: So you are planning to use an emulator to run an emulator. If it is even possible I would expect the performance to be so bad as to be unusable. It might help if you explain more about your project. Why do you need to run this specific virtual machine? What does it do that can't be done natively on the Pi?

Answer (score 0):

ExaGear is application level emulator. It means it can emulate separate application but not full OS.
Virtualbox is very system software and require new kernel modules and emulation of full OS.
So, you can not run virtualbox with exagear until they implement system level emulation.